# Created <button> using .innerHTML. When clicked, button isn't calling function in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, innerhtml

Using Angular, I am creating a countdown timer app. When the timer reaches a certain point, the timer stops, a notification sound is played and a `div` with a `button` is created.

***Like so...***

***HTML:***

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

***Javascript:***

```
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= '<div id="break-div"><button id="4"ng-click="timerControl.resetTimer()">Back to work!</button></div>'
```

***resetTimer() function inside of Angular `timerControl` controller***

```
this.resetTimer = function(){
    console.log(111)
    _this.resetWorkFlow = true;
}
```

It creates the button fine enough, but when I click it to call the `resetTimer()` function inside of the `timerControl` Angular controller, it isn't even entering the function, otherwise the `console.log(111)` would be showing `111` in my Google Dev Tools in Google Chrome. Seems like it could be an issue with the `DOM` or something like that. I tried using `jQuery` and it seems like there isn't much information about this out there. Anyone encounter this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular doesn't know that you did the `.innerHTML` assignment. You have to tell it, by invoking `$compile`. See the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

There's a quick tutorial about the process here: 
http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

Comment: @tangentstrom Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Where do you put your directives? In the corresponding controller of the template?

Comment: @tangentstrom Also, I've never made a directive before, nothing really seems to make sense. :/

Comment: Also, I don't really understand the docs. What does $compile do anyway?

Comment: The `$compile` service is where the JavaScript for the `ng-click` directive is stored. When you use the `$compile` service it instantiates the stored JavaScript and links it to the scope that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this just with Angular (without jQuery) and the variables you have set up in the view's controller.

You could handle the creation of the button using an ng-if directive and manage this condition for button creation through controller variables (scope of controller being vm below). Then call the resetTimer() function within the view's controller.

For example:

```
<div ng-if="vm.resetWorkFlow">
    <button id="4" ng-click="vm.resetTimer()">Back to work!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that didn't work. I think it has to do with the fact that the content I am displaying to the page is dynamic on the DOM (since I am using innerHTML()) and angular doesn't know that that button exists because of the corresponding disconnect...